# Malloc with a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, malloc

I am trying to create a dynamically allocated array of type struct, but am running into some issues. Namely the program crashes at the fclose command at the end of the program. After commenting this line out, the program crashes on return 0, so I am assuming there are some issues with my file I/O coding, and also an issue with my allocation of memory. My goal is to fill the values that are included in the struct host with values from a text file. Code below:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct host_struct {
    int x, y, z, w;
    char os[8];
} host;


int main(void)
{
    host *ipArray = NULL;
    int numOfIps = 0;
    char tempFileCharVal = 'a';
    char fileString[8];
    int test;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
FILE *hostFile;

    hostFile = fopen("hosts.txt", "r");

    while (fscanf(hostFile, "%c", &tempFileCharVal) != EOF)      //Nested loops to find number of ips, relies on there being a new line at the end of each IP address.
    {
        if (tempFileCharVal == '\n')
        {
            numOfIps++;
        }
    }

    ipArray = malloc(numOfIps * sizeof(*ipArray));                    //Allocates memory to array of ip addresses based on number of IP addresses and size of type host.


    fclose(hostFile);                                   //Reset hostFile to beginning of file.
    hostFile = fopen("hosts.txt", "r");


    for (i = 0; i < (numOfIps); i++)                  //Iterate through IPs, values within IPs, and values within hostFile to assign values to ipArray.
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; fscanf(hostFile, "%c", &tempFileCharVal) != '.'; k++)  //?? doesn't end loop if tempFileCharVal = '.'
            {
                if ((tempFileCharVal == ' ' || tempFileCharVal == '\n' || tempFileCharVal == '.') & j != 0) //?? Had to add this if statement to compensate for strange loop behavior.
                {
                    break;
                }
                if ((j == 0) & tempFileCharVal == '\n')
                {
                    fscanf(hostFile, "%c", &tempFileCharVal);
                }
                if ((j == 0) & (tempFileCharVal == '.' || tempFileCharVal == EOF))
                {
                    break;
                }
                fileString[k] = tempFileCharVal;
            }
            fileString[k] = '\0';
            switch (j)
            {
            case 0:
                ipArray[i].x = atoi(fileString);
                break;
            case 1:
                ipArray[i].y = atoi(fileString);
                break;
            case 2:
                ipArray[i].z = atoi(fileString);
                break;
            case 3:
                ipArray[i].w = atoi(fileString);
                break;
            case 4:
                strcpy(ipArray[i].os, fileString);
                ipArray[i].os[k] = '\0';
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    //fclose(hostFile);
    free(ipArray);
    return(0);

}
```

Comment: `sizeof(ipArray)` is the size of a pointer, because `ipArray` is a pointer.

Comment: Did that fix it? I guess I should re-post it as an answer then :P

Comment: Aaaaand, that fixed it, been stressing about that one for a while. Thanks again.

Comment: `tempFileCharVal == EOF` is a mistake. `EOF` is an `int` and can't safely be stored in a `char`.   In fact you never try to store `EOF` in the character anyway so this test doesn't make sense.

Comment: `fscanf(hostFile, "%c", &tempFileCharVal) != '.'` is a mistake: the return value of fscanf is the number of items successfully read, or EOF.  It won't be `.` .  In all of your cases it'd be better check `fscanf(...) == 1` , or perhaps even better, use `fgetc` instead of `fscanf` .

Comment: The `k` loop needs checks that it doesn't run out of bounds

Comment: hmm, what do `hosts.txt` contains? is it list of IPv4s?

Comment: Thanks for the comments M.M, I had some wrong ideas about the value of EOF and the return value of fscanf.

Comment: ibrohimislam, yes indeed

Answer (score 1):

<s>You have to be careful in this line:</s>

```
ipArray = malloc(numOfIps * sizeof(*ipArray));
```

'ipArray' is of type Pointer! You need considerably more memory though. The correct yay to do it would be to write:

```
ipArray = malloc(numOfIps * sizeof(struct host_struct));
```

EDIT: I now see this has been commented before, seems I'm late to the party, sorry! ;-)

EDIT: I was wrong, hope I have not confused anyone!

Comment: Phil, the `malloc` call is fine. `sizeof (*ipArray)` is the `sizeof (` *the dereferenced pointer* `)`, this is *exactly the same* as `sizeof(struct host_struct)`. Fix that and I'll remove the downvote. (however, fixing that and the remainder of the answer is quite thin, so best to delete and I'll remove the downvote). Let me know if you have any questions about this and I'm happy to further explain.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for pointing that out! It is clear to me, now that I have looked at it again. I did not know this would work

Comment: Fair enough - We all have that happen one in a while. I find crow tastes best with a pinch of salt... What is the adage *do unto others*? I wish more people on SO had the integrity to handle downvotes in this manner. I guess all each of us can do is to be an example.

Comment: Classy response to criticism @Phil.  It's the best way to learn.  Well done.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you. I have to give you props too for the way you handled and explained your downvote. Was one of the better examples for criticism/correction!